# Spark not correctly installed with HDP 2.3 via Ambari?

Tags: apache-spark, ambari

I am attempting to install HDFS, YARN, Spark, etc. on a local cluster of CentOS 6.6 machines using Ambari 2.1.0 and HDP 2.3. I already managed to botch the upgrade from HDP 2.2 so I erased all the HDP 2.2 packages + Ambari before starting over. I am able to get through most of the Cluster Install Wizard without a problem, but on the "Install, Start and Test" phase, I receive the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/after-INSTALL/scripts/hook.py", line 38, in <module>
    AfterInstallHook().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 218, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/after-INSTALL/scripts/hook.py", line 35, in hook
    link_configs(self.stroutfile)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/after-INSTALL/scripts/shared_initialization.py", line 91, in link_configs
    _link_configs(k, json_version, v)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/after-INSTALL/scripts/shared_initialization.py", line 156, in _link_configs
    conf_select.select("HDP", package, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/functions/conf_select.py", line 241, in select
    shell.checked_call(get_cmd("set-conf-dir", package, version), logoutput=False, quiet=False, sudo=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 70, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 92, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 140, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 291, in _call
    raise Fail(err_msg)
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'conf-select set-conf-dir --package spark --stack-version 2.3.0.0-2557 --conf-version 0' returned 1. spark not installed or incorrect package name
```

The check script appears to be looking for spark in /usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557. This is what I see in that directory

```
ls /usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/
etc  hadoop  hadoop-hdfs  hadoop-mapreduce  hadoop-yarn  ranger-hdfs-plugin  ranger-yarn-plugin  usr  zookeeper
```

One one of the slave machines that complains, it appears that spark has been "installed"

```
# yum list installed | grep spark
spark_2_3_0_0_2557.noarch
spark_2_3_0_0_2557-master.noarch
spark_2_3_0_0_2557-python.noarch
spark_2_3_0_0_2557-worker.noarch
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Some components are at level 2.3.0.0-2557 and some others are at 2.3.2.0-2621.

In my case I had an issue with Zookeeper, so in `/usr/hdp/current` I linked

```
zookeeper-client -> /usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/zookeeper
zookeeper-server -> /usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/zookeeper
```

This fixed the install issue, but not starting services.